# Core data fetch crash on iOS 8 only

Tags: core-data, ios8, swift3

I'm using core data in a project and it breaks on fetch...on iOS 8, but not on any other iOS version. The error I'm getting is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath myId not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Entity id=1>'
```

I don't understand this at all, the `myId` has always been there and it works fine with iOS 9 and 10.I've tried removing the app and installing it again, but to no avail. It happens on both the simulator and on device.

This is my code executing the fetch

```
static func fetch(_ sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, entityName: String) -> [NSManagedObject] {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    var fetchedObjects = [NSManagedObject]()
    do {
        fetchedObjects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch {
        log.error("error")
    }
    return fetchedObjects
}
```

It breaks inside the `do`-statement and doesn't throw an error. On iOS 9.0+ it doesn't throw any errors either. The code is written using Swift 3.

Comment: Please show the call incl. predicate, entityName aso.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. On iOS 9+ my entityName is correct, on iOS <9 it's not. Have no idea why yet, but that explains why it won't find the keypath.

Comment: Welcome. If you post the code, maybe someone can tell why.